# How to determine printer model in powershell or python?

Tags: python, powershell, printing

I need a script that will give me the printer name and the model of the device. I have over 100 printers that are different models.. some Ricoh, some HP, etc. The common thing that I can get is the printer driver. However, if some devices use the Universal drivers, this doesn't help me any. I want the actual model (i.e. Ricoh Aficio MP 4001). How can I do this with Powershell or Python?

I have tried using the Win32_Printer in Powershell but it cannot give me the actual model of the printer.

Thanks!

Comment: this smells like bad design... why would you need this info? I think the best you can hope for is the info from win32printer

Comment: We are trying to track inventory and see which devices there are on the network.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've already tried this, but you can check what methods are available via Get-Member:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer | Get-Member
```

Do any of the following give you what you need?

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer | % { $_.DeviceId }
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer | % { $_.PNPDeviceId }
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. Unfortunately, the above will not give me what I need. The Win32_Printer object does not seem to actually store this information for some reason. The DeviceId listed above gives the actual print queue name while the PNPDeviceId returns nothing for my printers.